# How to disable tooltip in highcharts gauge?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to disable [tooltip for gauge](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.tooltip) but no matter what I do, it doesn't work.

I tried to place:

```
tooltip: {
   enabled: false
}
```

under `chart`, `pane`, `series` ...

Here is a demo I use: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpyy732d/)

and this is a code:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
            tooltip: {
             enabled: false
            }
        },
                exporting: {enabled: false},
        title: {
            text: 'meetings',
            //align: 'bottom'
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: 10,
                 style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize:'18px'
                    }
        },

        pane: {
        tooltip: {
             enabled: false
            },
            startAngle: -150,
            endAngle: 150,
            background: [{
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFF'],
                        [1, '#333']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '109%'
            }, {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#333'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                outerRadius: '107%'
            }, {
                // default background
            }, {
                backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '105%',
                innerRadius: '103%'
            }]
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
        tooltip: {
             enabled: false
            },
            min: 0,
            max: max,

            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 0,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#666',

            tickPixelInterval: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 0,
            tickColor: '#666',
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            title: {
                text: '',
                y: 150,
                 style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize:'18px'
                    }
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: color_threshold_values[0],
                color: '#DA2626' 
            }, {
                from: color_threshold_values[0],
                to: color_threshold_values[1],
                color: '#F19E26' 
            }, {
                from: color_threshold_values[1],
                to: color_threshold_max,
                color: '#88A61F'
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Count',
            data: [data.count],

            dataLabels: {
            enabled:false,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    padding: 5,
                    shadow: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize:'25px'
                    }
                },

        }]

    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding it to the config object itslef?

http://jsfiddle.net/hesonazx/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  chart: {
  ...
});
```

This is based on the documentation.  Notice that the [`toottip` property for a guage type chart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<gauge>.tooltip) doesn't have an `enabled` option.  The [general `tooltip` property does however](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.enabled).

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `.highcharts-tooltip{opacity: 0;}`

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/dpyy732d/2/

Comment: well, opacity 0 means that DOM still exists, its not clear way.Hanks anyways

Comment: @snaggs Joseph's answer is better, however if you `.highcharts-tooltip{display: none}` it wont exist lol